# localhost .htaccess not working?

Tags: apache2

Now i install WordPress then BuddyPress, after the install buddypress i run the site, home page was run, when click the other page link the page was not working. show this error

Not Found

The requested URL /Repo/website/groups/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

After then i check my local htaccess, here is all are ok, but why the problem is showing.
Here is my local htaccess ..

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) or [ScriptAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias) in .htaccess files (look at the Context link in these manual pages).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure enable mod_rewrite module is in your apache2.conf? if you can access via ssh you can try this.

```
#enable mod_rewrite module
sudo a2enmod mod_rewrite

#to restart your apache2 service
sudo service apache2 restart
```